# What are the MIME types for .po and .mo files?

Tags: mime-types

Have a good day. I have a small admin panel in my site, where i can upload .po and .mo files via form with POST method. I want to check the MIME type for these files on server side in php.

If the files were images, it should be like this:

```
$allowedTypes = array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif');
if ($_FILES[$i]['type'] == $allowedTypes[$j]) {
echo "ok";
// some code
}
else
{
echo "oh, please, no hacking here";
}
```

But i don't know the MIME types of .po (human-readable file with translation strings for multi-lang site) and .mo (machine-readable file with translation strings for multi-lang site). How can i make this check?

Comment: How much research did you do? 30 seconds on google reveals https://filext.com/file-extension/PO and others which suggest the same, for example. And of course application/octet-stream can always be used as a fallback for otherwise unspecified cases.

Comment: P.S. the basic question "what is the mime type for X" has nothing to do with PHP specifically.

Comment: for .po files i tried `$allowedTypes = array('text/x-gettext-translation');`, but it does not validate my .po files...Though it (.po) is described as text/x-gettext-translation on the link given by Adyson

Comment: Well, what value is actually being sent by the browser in `$_FILES[$i]['type']` for such files? Just because a MIME type is suggested doesn't _necessarily_ mean that the browser knows about it, if it's an uncommon / non-standard one. You asked what the mime type was, and I gave you a suggestion as to what the accepted standard is, but you also need to take reality into account. It may be worth testing this in multiple browsers.

Comment: Yes, i printed the $_FILES[$i]['type'] - and browser thinks, that .po is 'application/octet-stream' (Chrome). But .php files are also 'application/octet-stream', so, it is not safe to use this for validation. What else can i do?

Comment: test the MIME type _and_ the extension. Nothing is foolproof because anything can be spoofed on the client side, but those in combination should stop most things.

Comment: Yes, so far so good, but for this time this can be a solution. Thanks, have a good time, mr. ADyson